# Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c, weblogic9.x

I'm using Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0.

I have deleted the contents of `/wls_domains/mydomain/servers/admin_mydomain/data/store/default & diagnostics`, and also the contents of `/wls_domains/mydomain/servers/admin_mydomain/tmp`

Now I cannot start the admin server and it is throwing below exception. Can someone please help me on this?

```
<27-Feb-2015 08:32:51 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141227> <Making a backup copy of the configuration at /wls_domains/mydomain/config-original.jar.>
<27-Feb-2015 08:32:51 o'clock GMT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.addFilesToJar(JarFileUtils.java:88)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.addFilesToJar(JarFileUtils.java:116)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.addFilesToJar(JarFileUtils.java:116)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.createJarFileFromDirectory(JarFileUtils.java:214)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.createJarFileFromDirectory(JarFileUtils.java:190)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.createJarFileFromDirectory(JarFileUtils.java:149)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.JarFileUtils.createJarFileFromDirectory(JarFileUtils.java:135)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigBackup.createJarFileFromConfig(ConfigBackup.java:168)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigBackup.createJarFileFromConfig(ConfigBackup.java:153)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigBackup.saveOriginal(ConfigBackup.java:54)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.<init>(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:139)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(RuntimeAccessService.java:41)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:895)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:572)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:471)
        at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:74)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are supposed to remove anything from the data directory.  You could try shutting down the environment, moving admin_mydomain directory to a temporary directory (say /tmp/admin_mydomain) and then restarting the environment.  WebLogic should then rebuild these directories.  Keep the /tmp/admin_mydomain directory in case this does not work then you can just move it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now, found out that someone has started the servers as "root" so some files has been created with the "root"'s permission. So the actual weblogic domain user failing to open up those files. I just restored the config folder and now its working

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem deleting the **DAT** in this directory **servers/AdminServer/data/store/diagnostics**. Please make a backup and try it.